# Java charAt() Error

Tags: java

I am new to java and don't know why I am getting this error or how to fix it. Any help please?

> Word.java:42: cannot find symbol
>
> symbol  : method length()
>
> location: class char[]
>
> ```
>   char finalLetter = letters.charAt(letters.length()-1);
>                               ^               ^
> ```
>
> Thanks~~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `letters` is a `char[]`. You need to have a `String` object to do that.

so either convert it to a String

```
String str = new String(letters);
char finalLetter = str.charAt(str.length() - 1);
```

or use directly as a char[]

```
char finalLetter = letters[letters.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with an array, array has a .length property and you index it directly like below...

```
String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
char[] letters = alphabet.toCharArray();
System.out.println( String.format( "Char at %d is %c", letters.length - 1, letters[ letters.length - 1 ] ) );
// Char at 25 is z
```

If you want to work with a String as a collection of characters, then you have a .length() method and a .charAt(int index) method to do the same thing.

So what does you actual Java class look like?